# Android-Facebook: How to share Youtube Video using ShareOpenGraphContent

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, youtube

How to share a Youtube Video on Facebook using open [graph share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/android).

This is what I been trying, it creates a post but it does not take me to youtube.

```
            String actionName = "play";
            String objectName = "song";
            String nameSpace = "myNameSpace";
            String videoUrl = "https://youtubeUrl";
            String objectType = "music.song";

            ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                    .putString("og:type", objectType)
                    .putString("og:image", imageUrl)
                    .putString("og:video:url", videoUrl)
                    .putString("og:title", item.getSnippet().getTitle())
                    .build();

            ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                    .setActionType(nameSpace + ":" + actionName)
                    .putObject(objectName, object)
                    .build();

            ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                    .setPreviewPropertyName(objectName)
                    .setAction(action)
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(videoUrl))
                    .build();

            ShareDialog.show(context, content);
```